# Algorithm of shuf command in linux

Tags: algorithms

Which **algorithm** is used for generating random permutations in ***shuf*** command in linux

Comment: This is nowhere *near* a computer *science* question. There is [unix.SE], but this one you should answer for yourself by inspecting documentation and/or code of the command, or contacting the support channels.